# Prove that $\operatorname{lcm}$ of [$\binom{n}{1}$, $\binom{n}{2}$, ... ,$\binom{n}{n}$] = $\operatorname{lcm}(1, 2, ...,n+1)/(n+1)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, combinations, gcd-and-lcm

How to prove that:
$$\operatorname{lcm}\left(\binom{n}{1}, \binom{n}{2}, \ldots, \binom{n}{n}\right) = \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(1, 2, \ldots, n+1)}{n+1}$$

There is a hint: 
$p$ is a prime and consider the highest power of $p$ in $\binom{n}{k}$, that is $p^e \:||\: \binom{n}{k}$, e is the highest power of p.

Comment: What have you tried(especially with the hint? Also consider this HINT: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$

Comment: Have you tried following the hint? Where did that lead? And independently of that, do you see how the hint would help?

Comment: @NaitikMundra I also prove that the highest power of p in $lcm(1, 2, ...,n+1)$ and I notice that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ but I don't know how to combine them together

Comment: @Arthur Actually I don't know what is the relationship between the highest power and lcm

Comment: @Gangmen what is the highest power of p in the lcm? Your comment does not make that clear.

Comment: By the way, the LCM is the product of the highest powers of the primes. So, in case of lcm(48,32) => 16 = $2^4 3^1$ and 32 = $2^5 3^0$. Highest power of 2 is 5 and 3 is 1. So LCM = $2^5 3^1$ = 96

Comment: @NaitikMundra Thanks for your comment and I know the highest power $r$ of p in $lcm(1, 2, ...,n+1)$ satisfies that $p^r\le n+1 < p^{r+1}$

Comment: @NaitikMundra Your comments really inspire me and I have some new thought about the problem.

Comment: I'm just curious: If you don't know the relationship between highest prime powers and lcm, how would you calculate the lcm of, say, 12 and 18?

Comment: @Arthur I am sorry that I didn't make it clear, actually I didn't know the relationship between highest power of p in lcm(1,2, n+1) and highest power of p in  LHS. And I may use the gcd and the product of two numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemma: $[\frac{n}{p}]-[\frac{n-k}{p}]-[\frac{k}{p}]\le 1$

Note that $$v_p(\binom{n}{k})=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} [\frac{n}{p^i}]-[\frac{n-k}{p^i}]-[\frac{k}{p^i}]$$

Suppose $p^e\le n+1 <p^{e+1}$ for some $p<n$, then $v_p(\operatorname{lcm}(1, ..., n+1))=e$.
We need to prove that
$$(n+1)v_p(\operatorname{lcm}(\binom{n}{1}, ..., \binom{n}{n}) = v_p((n+1)\operatorname{lcm}(\binom{n}{1}, ..., \binom{n}{n}) = e$$

Now $(n+1)\binom{n}{k} = (k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$, so $$v_p((n+1)\operatorname{lcm}(\binom{n}{1}, ..., \binom{n}{n}) = \max\limits_{1\le k \le n}v_p((k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1})=\max\limits_{1\le k\le n}(v_p(k+1)+v_p\binom{n+1}{k+1})$$

Let $v_p(k+1)=s$ then by the lemma $v_p(\binom{n+1}{k+1}) \le e-s$, therefore $v_p((k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}) \le e$ for all $k=1, 2, ..., n$.

Also if $k=p^e-1$, $v_p((k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}) \ge e$. So we are done.

Comment: Might just be me, but this answer is a bit hard to read. Could you format it a bit better? I cannot understand what you have written.

Comment: @NaitikMundra I tried to format it better. Can you read it now? LaTex is hard to learn..

Comment: definitely. Thanks. Great solution.

Comment: Thank you and it is an excellent answer.

Comment: @Hypernova I have a little question: why $v_p((n+1)lcm(\binom{n}{1}, ..., \binom{n}{n}) = v_p(\max\limits_{1\le k\le n}(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1})$ holds?

Comment: @Gangmenb $v_p(n)$ stands for maximum power of $p$ dividing n. The lcm also gives the maximum power of $p$ among $\binom{n}{1}, …, \binom{n}{n}$. So by $(n+1)\binom{n}{k} = (k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$, the equation holds.